# How can I use a For-Loop to return a new array from an old one

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, operators

I have a set of students from *two* different grading systems.

**First grading system**
One grading system is defined as grades being from 1-5 where 3 and above means you pass the course.

**Second grading system**
The other grade system has the following grades A, A-, B, B-, C, C- where A is the top grade and C is the lowest passing grade.

The task
Given the following array allStudents representing all students and their grades, I am trying to construct a new array studentsWhoPass containing all students who pass.

let allStudents = [
'A',
'B-',
1,
4,
5,
2
]

let studentsWhoPass = [];

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

```js
let allStudents = [
    'A',
    'B-',
    1,
    4,
    5,
    2
  ]
  
  let studentsWhoPass = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++) {
    if (allStudents >= 'A' && allStudents > 3) {
        return studentsWhoPass.push(allStudents);
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In addition, you are operating on the array itself (allStudents) instead of the current element (allStudents[i]) inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

- return in the loop will stop the loop. It is not needed in a loop
  It is needed in a map or filter and not allowed outside a function
- You need to access the item with [i]
- You have a mix of letters and digits. You need to treat them separately
- "B..." is > "A..." so we need to test the actual string

Here I test the letters with isNaN (is not a number)

It passes all letters > `C-` and all numbers >= 3

```js
const allStudents = [ 'A','A-','B-',1,4,5,2 ];

const getPassingStudents = () => allStudents
  .filter(student => {
    if (isNaN(student)) 
      return "ABC".includes(student.slice(0,1)) && student != "C-";
    return student > 3;
});    
    

console.log(
  getPassingStudents()
)
```

Comment: I am so thankful. This is classic. All feedback has been duly noted.

Comment: @davidodolofin Please see new code. I updated to be more logical It passes all letters > C- and all numbers >= 3

Answer (score 0):

```js
let allStudents = [
    'A',
    'B-',
    1,
    4,
    5,
    2
  ]
  
  let studentsWhoPass = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < allStudents.length; i++) {
    if (allStudents[i] == 'A' || allStudents[i] == 'B' || allStudents[i] == 'C' || allStudents[i] == 'A-' || allStudents[i] == 'B-' || allStudents[i] > 3) {
        studentsWhoPass.push(allStudents[i]);
    }
  }
console.log(studentsWhoPass);
```

**NOTE**:-

- return statement can only be there in any function any outside the function, you can just update and push the value into the array
- You were trying to push whole array put here we'll just push the element in the array e.g. `studentsWhoPass.push(allStudents[i]);`
- In the if statement, you were checking whether the whole array for a certain condition but you will have to check for the element same like the above example
- for checking for the character, we could check using the ASCII code but it could become confusing, to make it simple we are checking for individual letters
- Also, instead of `&&`(and) operator we are using `||`(or) operator so that every condition for every element need not be true but atleast one condition should be true

I think this will solve your problem, Thank you!

Comment: Wow! Perfect answer. I can not wait to get to this level. The code works. Thanks so much , man.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a map of each grade along with its equivalent score, then it's easy to filter students with an equivalent score of 3 or above using `Array.filter()`

```js
let allStudents = [ 'A', 'B-', 1, 4, 5, 2, 'C-' ]
  
// One can customize as necessary..
let gradeMap = { 'A': 7, 'A-': 6, 'B': 5, 'B-': 4, 'C': 3, 'C-': 2};

const passingScore = 3;

function studentPassed(input) {
    return (gradeMap[input] || input) >= passingScore;
}

let studentsWhoPass = allStudents.filter(studentPassed)
console.log('Passing students:', studentsWhoPass)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```